# pyQt QTableView does not display number (int, float, etc.)

Tags: python, filter, pyqt, qtableview

I have a problem with QTableView and putting data into it. Text (strings) are displayed fine and can be sorted and filtered using a proxy and QStandardItemModel

```
 self.material_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
 self.proxy = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
 self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.material_model)
 self.t_material.setModel(self.proxy)
```

However, if I try to put numbers/values into the table it wont show up at all using the following snippet:

```
for row in xrange(0, len(self.material.data)):
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(self.material.data[row]['name']))
    self.material_model.setItem(row, 0, item)

    item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
    item2.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole,float(999.99))
    self.material_model.setItem(row, 1, item2)
```

I've tried several variants including Qt.DisplayRole instead of Qt.EditRole. But from other posts I have the feeling, that not every method and functionality is implemented in pyQt and therefore was hesitating to play around too much (I've already invested a couple of hours, though). And now I'm hoping that you can help me to solve this problem. Maybe, my approach is not suitable for what I try to do, which is basically filter the content by text (names) and values (interval). I am using pyQt, Windows7 and the data originates from an SQLite DB using an self written query wrapper instead of QtSQL.

Any insight is appreciated!

Cheers,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try converting the numbers to strings before inserting them into the table, it wont affect your program as it is just for display purpose.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works, however, the sorting is not right, because e.g. 10 is not followed by 11, but 100. Also, I doubt that the filtering on an interval will work. Please correct me, if I am wrong. Is the whole QTableView supposed to work only with strings?

Comment: data display widgets like QTableView, QListView only take QString as input in their addItem method. You can sort the item before converting them to strings and inserting them in the table.

Answer (score 2):

I found a somewhat elegant solution to this. Just be more careful how you format your number strings. Add spaces in the front as placeholders for 0 digits. So if you want your numbers to be length 10 strings with 4 decimal spaces:

```
float_as_str = "{:10.4f}".format(float_i_started_with)
```

In the end, when you sort them everything works out. The only downsides are:

1. You have to explicitly tell it what the maximum length of your numbers are. In this case it will sort any numbers < 10^6 (6 comes from 10-4).
2. It gives it a right-align look.